# PrimeNG: Click on a li element of p-dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown, primeng

I am using a p-dropdown in my project from library PrimeNG (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v8.2.7-lts/#/dropdown). Well, what I want to do is to group the elements of the dropdown and that I have achieved. My question is, is it possible that the elements that are in bold (in the picture it would be for example Germany or USA) can be selected? Now, if I select it, it does not appear as selected in the dropdown. Is there any way?

[image]

Another option would be to find some way to have the elements listed as you can see in the second picture but using the PrimeNG dropdown element.

[image]

- Version Angular: 8.2.14
- Version PrimeNG: 8.1.1

Comment: Please eloborate, what do you want to achieve by selecting the group elements? Your dropdown declared "Select a Car". A group like "Germany" is obviously not a car. Maybe there is an alternative approach for your goal.

Comment: It seems to me you don't want a group select at all, but rather a standard dropdown but with parent and child entries shown. I guess you could achieve this by dynamically assigning child classes (to handle the indentation et al). That way all the items would be selectable. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Mmm okay. You are right. I understand. What I want to achieve is that the elements of my dropdown are like in the second picture (indexed) and you can select any of them but I can't use an alternative library. Do you have any idea? @MoxxiManagarm

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Do you have any examples of how to do that? @DarrenStreet

Comment: Well you could use an expression inline, something like NgClass, but you would need to loop over your array to establish the parent or child relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use the item-template and create a way to append the indent to the item (e.g. pipe (postcalculated), extended SelectItem (precalculated)...) depending on the index value. Don't keep the group.

I mean something similar to this:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="myOptions">
    <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item"> 
        {{ option.label | addIndentSpaces }}
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

Please refer to the templating section "Custom Content" within the docs.

Comment: this will work  but I thing he can solve this but just update the label when her get the responds because it just a prefix 